# Attach data or array index to anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some javascript/jquery code that dynamically populates an unordered list with a bunch of list items.  In the list items I have a link and I want to associate some data with that link which is generated like so:

```
var thing1 = { name: 'My Object' };
var thing2 = { name: 'My Other Object' };
var li = $('<li></li><br />');
var aSel = $('<strong>' + thing1.name + '<br /><a class="btn btn-mini btn-success addDeal" href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="icon-plus"></i>Add Deal</a>';
li.append(aSel);
li.append(add);
$('#sidebar').append(li);
//This is in a loop so the same thing would happen with thing2, etc
```

would generate HTML like so:

```
<div id="results">
    <ul id="sidebar">
        <li>
            <strong>My Object</strong><br />
            <a class="btn btn-mini btn-success addDeal" href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="icon-plus"></i>Add Deal</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <strong>My Other Object</strong><br />
            <a class="btn btn-mini btn-success addDeal" href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="icon-plus"></i>Add Deal</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

So if the user clicks the first Add Deal link, I want to work with the `thing1` data elsewhere in my script.  If they second link is clicked on, I want to work with the `thing2` data.

The path I'm going down involves an array and some code that doesn't feel quite right to me.  I figure I'm missing something trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [jQuery.data](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) function to attach a "thing" to each of your links.  Right after the `var aSel =` line:

```
$('a', aSel).data('thing', thing1); // Select the anchor tag inside of 
                                    // aSel and attach thing1 to it
```

Then when the anchor tag is clicked, retrieve it with: `var thing = $(this).data('thing');`

Comment: I've been messing around with your suggestion in jsfiddle and it doesn't seem to work.  [Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/BigPete/rfUNB/)

Comment: I just wanted to add that [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BigPete/rfUNB/1/) works.  I just ended up doing `aSel.data('thing', thing1)` and that seems to work for some reason despite the amount of tags in there.  It's not immediately obvious to me why it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [HTML5 Custom Data Attributes (data-*)](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/) to achieve what you want.

Take special look at Using data- attributes with JavaScript.