# link between model dialog and caller function

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a list of images and a delete button attached with each image.

in click of delete button i have opened a popup for confirmation using twitter bootstrap modal with help of jquery event handler.

Now when i click on the confirmation button in the popup, how can i return a value to caller function (delete button), so that i can remove the image from dom?

Twitter Bootstrap Modal: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals

---

Following is the code i have used to call model dialog box:

```
$('.close-btn').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
    //$(this).parents('li').remove();
});
```

Comment: By pop up do you mean a new window or just the modal dialog?  I may have to change my answer.

Comment: I mean a modal dialog, created in html, and called with help of javascript.

Comment: Please see the Twitter Bootstrap Modal, i have mentioned in my question.

Comment: Then my answer is below is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the correct way of writing this, but it worked for me:

```
        $('.close-btn').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation()
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
            var elm = $(this).parents('li');
            $('.confirm-delete').click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(elm).remove();
                $('#myModal').modal('hide')
            })
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

The modal and all elements in it (form fields, buttons, pictures) are already part of the dom.  You just need to handle the submit, click or whatever event you want for the delete button.  No need to pass anything since a modal is already part of the current page.

```
$('.close-btn').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
    //$(this).parents('li').remove();
});

$('#confirmDeleteButton').click(function() {
    //code here to delete the associated picture
}
```

Comment: Thanks Pete, but i have multiple delete buttons and one confirmation dialog, how can i identify which delete button was clicked when i click on "confirmDeleteButton".

Comment: There are different methods.  You can dynamically assign a unique id to each button.  Using jQuery `data()` is another option and what I would use.  See my [question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10343441/attach-data-or-array-index-to-anchor-tag), it's the same as what you're trying to do except I was doing additional processing, not deleting.